# Padding for div inside of a div

Tags: html, css

hey guys I am currently learning html and css I just wanted to ask that I have a div inside of a div . I Just want the outer div to have a background colour of Blue and the inner div to be 50px from top and left of outer div .dimensions of my inner div are 200px by 80px but when I try to apply padding for the inner div it just increases it's dimensions by 50 instead of spacing it from the outer div and keeps sticks to the edge of outer div.
I also have an iframe inside of inner div if that may be the cause.

HTML

```css
.contact {
  background-color: rgba(0, 102, 204,0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 50px;

}
.social {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;

}
#fb {
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="social">
      <iframe id="fb" src="Somelink" width="200" height="21" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your code so we know what you've tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I understanding you correctly? Is this what you want?

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #00f;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
}

.inner > * {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <aside>This is your iframe or whatever</aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes exactly that but like following your code it gives spacing from the top from the outer div as well

Comment: I'm not following what the desired outcome is. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: hey as you can see from my code that my inner div is situated at the top left corner of my outer div and when I add padding 50px it just increases the dimensions of the inner div instead of centering or spacing like in your example. btw thanks for helping

Comment: You have a lot of extra css that doesn't really do anything. Why does the iframe have float:left for example? The margin-top on .social is also kind of misplaced, I think? It would really help if you would explain what your goal is.

Comment: oh the float:left in iframe was because I plan to add other elements inside the inner div as well which would be placed alongside this iframe. as for that margin-top and position:relative yeah it was wrong as I was just experimenting trying to align social inside contact ,with padding not working as I thought.

Comment: Thank you I got the answer looking at your code to place padding:50px in the outer div instead of the inner

Answer (score 0):

It's because the actual content width is calculated by width PLUS padding with the default "box-sizing: content-box".

You can set the box-sizing to border-box to get => total width = width + padding instead of "total width = width"

See [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

---

EDIT: I just read your question again. 
A padding pushed the **content** of the current element not the element itself. So you have to set a padding on the parent container.

Comment: Thank you so much got it by putting on the parent container